# Why access to mongodb only with vpn

Tags: c#, mongodb

On one of my servers I installed mongodb 4.2 and by default TLS is disable and I give access to all ip address to connect to my mongodb database but every time I try to connect to this server based on port 27017 by robo I face this error:

> Error: Network is unreachable. Reason: network error while attempting
>   to run command 'isMaster' on host

And whenever I try to connect by asp.net core i see this error

> TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server
>   using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{
>   ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :

But when I use VPN ,connection to my server is successful even without VPN I see connection listener in log file but without client metadata . I do not know what is the problem even I give access to all ip address.

please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Is your server reachable outside of your VPN? It doesn't sound like it. It's going to take more than just configuring your server inside your VPN to make it reachable from outside your network. You will probably need to get your network folks involved to expose the server to the outside.

Comment: I can access server without vpn but for mongodb I use vpn not to connect to server only for change my public ip address then I can connect to mongodb